# converting .VDI to .VHD CentOS will not boot

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have a CentOS vm created in VirtualBox. I need to convert it to VHD to use on my hyper-V server. I used the vbox manage tool and the conversion went fine. When i try to boot it up with Hyper-V it boots into emergency mode and doesn't actually boot. I have read some that this is because the UUID for the volume is different but i don't know how to fix that. Can you guys give me a hand? I'm not terribly proficient with centOS Linux so instructions would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

declare the uuid of the cloned / converted in grub OR see if you declare a /dev/sdxy

use something like disks from graphical  or  'lsblk -afm' in terminal

use the UUID given for the  intended volume when booting

(from a installer ---can be any OS so long as it has a disk analyser  (disk utility on mac and MOST linux installs or  disk management tool on Win)

conversely,  you reconvert using the --no-uuid flag/switch which will NOT copy it over theoretically eliminating the issue ALL together